# Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0". on Apache virtualhost

Tags: php, linux, laravel, apache, virtualhost

I'm trying to make a virtual host for a Laravel project using Apache2 on Ubuntu. I follow each step to configure it correctly, but when I'm going to visit, it displays the following error:

Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0".

I have checked my PHP version and I have the correct one. Here's my foo.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName foo.test
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/foo/public
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I think isnt nothing wrong. I'll apreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade the php version of the system. It requires **PHP version >= 7.4.0**

Comment: I have PHP 7.4.24 running on my system

Comment: run the command php -v in terminal and give me the output.